# Where to put a hotfix test in Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am building an application using Laravel, a bug was found, so, I would to know where to put the hotfix test. I have this tests structure:

Tests -> Feature -> Http -> MyControllerTest.php, more files...
Tests -> Unit-> Models-> MyModelTest.php, more files...

I know that I have to write a test for that bug, but I don't know where to put it, it is related to the authorization using tokens, some routes are not being protected, and it looks like I need to write a custom middleware I think, I am not sure yet, I was thinking to put it in a differente file in Feature/Http folder, something like HotFixTest.php?, or maybe in the same MyControllerTest.php file, I don't know where? what can I do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is, depending on what you have to do to fix the bug, I would:

- Instead of having `Tests -> Feature -> Http -> MyControllerTest.php` it should be `Tests -> Feature -> Htpp -> UserRegistration` (let's say that `MyController` allows a user to register).

  - This means you should write folder names for **FEATURE** tests like what they are, a *feature*, not a file, you don't care about the implementation (and that is how you are writting HTTP tests)
- If the fix requires you to fix the controller without creating new code outside it (no middlewares or anything similar), just create a new test inside the Test class
- If the fix requires a new middleware or something outside the controller, but "interacts" with the controller, for example, a middleware, a form request, etc (they are not inside or in the controller, but complements it), then create a new test class related to that feature or write the test inside the existing class like in the previous point.

  - Why?: because you are testing a feature. If you have URL `/user/123` and the bug is that it has no authntication, you have to create a new test in there, that will do a `GET` or whatever to `/user/123` and you should expect a `401` or `403`, but another normal test that if you do send the token, you get a `200` or whatever is successful for you. See that it is TIED to the feature. You have to do this for each route, do not unit test the middleware

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to fix that given BUG simply implementing a middleware, you can "cover" that implementation by simply written a UnitTest.

I have no context, but given a new file at `/app/Http/Middleware/TokenGuardMiddleare` you can create the test `/test/unit/Http/Middleware/TokenGuardMiddleare`

Comment: thanks for the response, let's imagine that is no required to write a custom middleware, let's say that is something bad in the controller, the MyControllerTest.php, then in the test/Feature/MyControllerTest.php I put a new test?